# java : append data in existing file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, r.java-file

i have a file DataFile.txt with few records. when i am adding new entry, it clears all the other records and saving only new one. but i want to append that record.

```
private void saveFile()
      {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("DataFile.txt"));


            String name ="";
            String ID="";
            String roomType ="";
            String meal="";
            int days=0;
            int tprice=0;


            for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
            {
                Customer c = myList.get(i);

                name = c.getName();
                ID = c.getID();
                roomType = c.getRoomItem();
                meal = c.getMealItem();
                days = c.getDaysIndex();
                tprice = c.getTotalPrice();

                out.println(name + "," + ID+ "," + roomType+ "," + meal+ "," + days+ "," + tprice);
            }
            out.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data saved successfully!","",
                                                              JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             System.out.println("save file fail");
          }
      } //end of the method
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can change to use the FileWriter constructor which takes a boolean `append` parameter:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("DataFile.txt", true));
```

However:

- `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions - I wouldn't use it if I were you
- `FileWriter` always uses the platform default encoding - I wouldn't use that, either. I'd use an `OutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` created with a specific encoding.

Comment: i am wondering that its working same despite adding the "true".

Comment: @Ravi: It shouldn't - that should be appending to the existing file.

Comment: i have a same method in another program and that hasn't a true parameter as well but that one is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Well if that's using the `FileWriter(String)` constructor, then something else is going on - because that *will* overwrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use FileWriter. It is not possible to define character encoding with FileWriter aand you will end up using system default encoding, which usually will not be what you want to use.

Instead use FileOutputStream and an OutputStreamWriter. Yes, it is an extra line of code, but that extra line is required if you want to write robust and bug free code.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true);
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
```

Using system default character encoding is the most common source for bugs. Make a habit of learning to not rely on system default character encoding (or system default time zone).